# How to start a new thread in JScript.NET

Tags: c#, jscript

I am starting a new thread in my Jscript.Net file like this :

```
  function clearinternalfaults( param : String)
 {

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(MyWorkItem);
 }

 public function MyWorkItem(state : Object) : void
 {
informationTextBox1.Text = "tesT";
 }
```

AS it should, it raises a cross thread operation exception. How can i solve this. I don't know if i can use Invoke on the main form. I know for sure that i can't declare delegates and events in Jscript.Net. Do you have any idea how to fix this ?

In fact, i have a delegate on my c# code in background.

I connect that delegate to my method :

```
 MyClass.myRF = clearinternalfaults;
```

so when i call in code

```
 myRF("test")
```

the clearinternalfauls should run, and it runs ok indeed. 
But in my case, if i try to update the GUI from there, it will block, and i don;t know why,so i am creating that thread to do the job for me.And the cross operation comes in right away .

If somebody knows some Jscript tricks, please give me a hand. Thanks.